# Deleting multiple rows based on value in one row using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Deleting multiple rows based on value in one row using dplyr

Let us say I have dataset like this

```
Pet   Day       Bite
Cow   Monday    No  
Cow   Tuesday   No  
Cow   Wednesday No  
Dog   Monday    No  
Dog   Tuesday   No  
Dog   Wednesday No  
Tiger Monday    No  
Tiger Tuesday   Yes  
Tiger Wednesday No
```

I want to create a new dataset which eliminates all pets which bites. My dataset should be

```
Pet   Day       Bite
Cow   Monday    No  
Cow   Tuesday   No  
Cow   Wednesday No  
Dog   Monday    No  
Dog   Tuesday   No  
Dog   Wednesday No
```

How can I do this using dplyr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `filter` link [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html)

Could do this with just `filter` and `any`. You `group_by` pet and if any of them are bite it will filter out the whole Pet category.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Pet) %>% filter(!any(Bite == "Yes"))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: Pet [2]
#  Pet   Day       Bite 
#  <fct> <fct>     <fct>
#1 Cow   Monday    No   
#2 Cow   Tuesday   No   
#3 Cow   Wednesday No   
#4 Dog   Monday    No   
#5 Dog   Tuesday   No   
#6 Dog   Wednesday No
```